# How can I use this Regression Plot on new data?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I'm trying to use this regression plot, but I haven't looked at one in ages.

[image]

I read it that for every 15.23 (x axis) increase in Population Density, there is a $0.95 (y axis) increase in Weekly Spending. But those results aren't making sense when I try and apply to another city.

Where am I going wrong?

Paper for context (Page 46): https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w28731/w28731.pdf

I'm trying to figure out the same value for Melbourne Australia's CBD which has a density of 68,420 per sq mile but (68420 / 15.23) * 0.95 = 4,267.82 per week, which is 15x the amount reported for NYC ($288 per week).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the log scale on the horizontal axis. Since the fit is a straight line (which, to be honest, does not make the faintest sense, given the obvious curvilinear relationship of the data points), this means that the expenditure is modeled as a linear function of the logarithm of density,

$$ y=\hat\beta_1\log x+\hat\beta_0. $$

We see in the picture that $\hat\beta_1=15.23$. A little twiddling shows that the $\log$ involved is the natural one (and not, say, base 10), and an intercept of about $\hat\beta_0=20$ gives roughly the line we see. (If the intercept is reported somewhere in the paper, feel free to correct this.)

[image: fit]

So you can now substitute the numbers for Melbourne:

$$ 15.23\log 68420+20\approx 190. $$

This is about 66% of the NYC figure and looks more reasonable.

R code:

```
xx <- c(50,10^(2:5))
ff <- function(dens)15.23*log(dens)+20
plot(xx,ff(xx),type="l",log="x",las=1,ylim=c(80,300))
ff(68420)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your thoughtful response. Have a great week.